# What type is "__main__.Example"?

Tags: python

I'm creating a class and checking the arguments for `__init__`.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a):
        for key, val in locals().items():
            print(type(val))
```

When I create this class, (something like `Example(14)`) I get `<class '__main__.Example'>` on the first line.
I know this is 'self', but what type is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__main__` prefix is present because your class is defined in your script's global scope.

```py
>>> class A:
...     pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>>
```

The type of `Example(14)` is... well, `Example`, since that's the class of which that object is an instance.

Comment: How could I check if something is/isn't equal to that type then?

Comment: `isinstance(some_object, Example)`

Comment: You're welcome @windows-weeb